# На какой слог идет ударение в названии расы Орокин в игре warframe

Tags: орфоэпия

На какой слог идет ударение в названии расы Орокин в игре warframe

Answer (score 1):

[Ударение на первый слог. Дискуссия здесь, например:](https://www.reddit.com/r/Warframe/comments/2po2cy/which_is_it_orokin_or_orokin/.) Также много видео с коментариями на Youtube; один пользователь даже признаётся, что он неправильно произносил сначала, и что ему делали много замечаний, и что теперь он говорит правильно: "Орокин".

Comment: Виктор, но там обсуждение идет на английском языке среди англоязычных пользователей. Следовательно, речь идет об ударении в английском языке, а не в русском. Есть ли у вас какие-нибудь источники, где бы говорилось об ударении в русском языке?

Comment: Нет, таких источников у меня нет.  Предположительно, название расы (народности) происходит от Oro- и -kin, но мы его ведь не переводим (Золото-родичи, Золотородцы), так что можно просто следовать произношению на английском, разве нет?

Comment: Следовать можно, я не отрицаю. но вопрос в том, следуют ли?

Comment: Будем надеяться, что игравшие в эту игру нас просветят.

Answer (score 0):

> так что можно просто следовать произношению на английском, разве нет?

Поскольку слово не фиксируется в общелитературных словарях (и вряд ли когда-нибудь туда попадет), не вижу причин отказываться от следования английскому произношение (поскольку оно не противоречит русской фонетике).